# Report Portal Jira Integration Issue

Tags: jira, reportportal

I'm facing an issue with **ReportPortal**. I've successfully installed a new server using Docker containers, and everything seems to be working fine. However, I encountered a problem when trying to integrate it with Jira.
The integration with Jira appears to be successful, as the connection status shows as "**Connected**." However, when I try to create a task on ReportPortal, I encounter an error message: "**Failed to Post Issue**."
I've checked and verified that all containers are healthy, and there are no apparent issues with the server or the setup. The problem seems to be specifically related to the Jira integration.
I'm seeking assistance in resolving this Jira integration issue. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Jira integration with ReportPortal